# File not uploading with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an issue when trying to upload a file. I have tried both in localhost and in a hosting server. What is strange about it is that I get error code 0 in `$_FILES['fichero']['error']` but anyway the file is never there. I checked permissions on temp dir and they are right. I also check with `is_uploaded_file` and I get a positive answer.

This is the code I am using with PHP and the form in the same file.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo '<p>File uploaded.</p>';
        if ($_FILES['fichero']['error'] == 0 && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo '<p>Successful upload.</p>';
            echo '<p>File is temporarily in: ' . $_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'] . '</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p>Problem with file upload.</p>';
        }
    }
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
        <p>Name: </p>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name">
        <p>File: </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3276800">
        <input type="file" name="fichero">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check http://in2.php.net/move_uploaded_filed  function to upload the file and sample code in the examples. In the above code you didn't performed the upload anywhere. Enjoy learning

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success. What's the problem? I don't see a question here. When you upload files you have to move them outside of PHP's temporary location otherwise they'll get deleted at the end of the script. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: 1) You can leave the action to "" 2) Don't define the max filesize in the form itself, do that in PHP 3) Where are you storing the file?

Comment: I added:
define('IMGPATH', '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/img/');
$target = IMGPATH . $_FILES['fichero']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'], $target);

But it does not work either. I cannot find the file anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: OK. Now it was only a permissions issue. Solved. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you should use move_uploaded_file to upload the file to a location in the server. You can also limit the upload by size , type etc. Please look into https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php for more info. is_uploaded_file only checks whether the file was uploaded using `HTTPPOST` method (means it doesn't upload the file).

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo '<p>File uploaded.</p>';
        $fileName = $_FILES["fichero"]["name"]; 
        $fileTmploc = $_FILES["fichero"]["tmp_name"];
        $filePath = "upload/".$fileName;
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmploc, $pathAndName)==TRUE){
            echo "Upload Successful";
        } else {
            echo "Upload Failed";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Please make an **upload** folder in your application root and give necessary write permissions.

Comment: I added: define('IMGPATH', '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/img/'); $target = IMGPATH . $_FILES['fichero']['name']; move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'], $target); But it does not work either. I cannot find the file anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: OK. Now it was only a permissions issue. Solved. Many thanks!!